# Error code 403 in Google+ api

Tags: google-plus, google-api-objc-client

I got "error": `{
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }`
When i try to fetch User Profile in Google+ api by https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me URL String.If anyone have any suggestion then please tell me as soon as possible.Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 9):

That message implies that you haven't set up a Google APIs console project.

1. Create a [Google APIs Console project](https://code.google.com/apis/console)
2. On the [Services pane](https://code.google.com/apis/console#:services), enable all of the APIs that your project requires.
3. On the [API Access pane](https://code.google.com/apis/console#:access), click **Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID**. A dialog opens. Fill in your project's information. Click **Next**
4. Choose the appropriate application type. Based on the tags you used for this post, I am guessing this is an iOS project so select **Installed application**.
5. Enter your bundle ID. You don't need to enter an App Store ID until your app is listed there.
6. Click **Create Client ID**.

You will see the client ID and client secret values. You will use these values to enable communication with your project and the Google APIs.

If you aren't already using it, see the [Google+ iOS SDK and documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/) for a full walk through. The task called "write moments" is similar in implementation and demonstrates how to connect to and use the Google+ REST APIs from within an iOS project that uses the SDK.

You'll need to specify the scope of plus.me to get the profile information.

Comment: I too got the error and the reason it shows is daily limit exceeded...
I am getting this error for google translate API... why is it so?

Comment: Same deal, all APIs require that you have a project and have the API turned on for that project and that you correctly pass your client ID from your app to the API.

Comment: I am getting this error even though my project is already registered.  Specifically, I get this error in Android 2.3 but it works fine in Android 4.1.

Comment: I am getting this error even though my project is already registered. I have ClientId,API KEY etc. I have turned on Google+ API access.I am getting this error in Android 4.2.

Comment: Same problem here, I use the client id and secret to do the OAuth dance and then use the credentials to make the API call. Still same error.

Comment: This error typically means something isn't quite right with credentials. For Android, that can be a mistake in the SHA1 or package name or the SHA1 was created with a different key than the app was built with.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and after much hunting I found that, in my case, the Authorization header with the access token was not set. Set `Authorization: "Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>"` in the header of the request of **EVERY** Google API call.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add a little information here in the rare case that someone runs into this problem.

I have an organization (ORG). I created a second channel (SC) with some playlists, that referenced videos from ORG.

I made the mistake of assuming that because ORG owned SC, that I could use the same oauth credentials from ORG to access both. I was wrong.

I switched credentials and was confused when I could access the playlists but not the videos. Again, I needed credentials for each one separately to access the resources on the respective channel.

Lame, but that was how it was.

Answer (score 0):

BrettJ's answer will cover most of the bases. However, you will also get this error - even when your credentials are properly authenticated - when the *scope* is not properly set up. I would check the scope setting in your OAuth dance.  Make sure your user is permitted to do the thing your code is trying to help them do.

Comment: Comment under the answer you're referring to - it's not an answer.

Comment: I can't. You need 50 rep to do it. This answer would have been good for me to read if I had come across it. And you downvote it? Is this how all of SO works?

Answer (score 0):

On top of what BrettJ has mentioned, it is important to send the authorization header for the request done to fetch UserProfile in google+ API.

For example, Add the following header
key: Authorization
value: Bearer ya29.Ci-cA_CywoVdVG#######

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I also got this error when using rclone to sync files and my firewall wasn't configured to allow that traffic.

Comment: You may want to leave a comment to the question instead of writing an answer here.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that yet, not enough rep