# Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup error

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file from google drive using node.js. This is my first attempt to use google sdks so I just followed the instructions and copied the code from the samples. I can succesfully get the metadata from the files present in my gdrive , but whenever I am trying to download a file, it is throwing the error. Please find ahead the code snippet I am using below which is nothing but the examples provided in the documentation.

```
            var fs = require('fs');
            var readline = require('readline');
            var google = require('googleapis');
            var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
            var request = require("request");

            // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
            // at ~/.credentials/drive-nodejs-quickstart.json
            //var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
            var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
            /* var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
                process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/'; */
            var TOKEN_DIR = process.env.USERPROFILE + '/.credentials/'; 
            var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';

            // Load client secrets from a local file.
            fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
              if (err) {
                console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
                return;
              }
              // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
              // Drive API.
              authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
            });

            /**
             * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
             * given callback function.
             *
             * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
             * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
             */
            function authorize(credentials, callback) {
              var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
              var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
              var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
              var auth = new googleAuth();
              var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

              // Check if we have previously stored a token.
              fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
                if (err) {
                  getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
                } else {
                  oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
                  callback(oauth2Client);
                }
              });
            }

            /**
             * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
             * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
             *
             * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
             * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
             *     client.
             */
            function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
              var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
                access_type: 'offline',
                scope: SCOPES
              });
              console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
              var rl = readline.createInterface({
                input: process.stdin,
                output: process.stdout
              });
              rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
                rl.close();
                oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                    return;
                  }
                  oauth2Client.credentials = token;
                  storeToken(token);
                  callback(oauth2Client);
                });
              });
            }

            /**
             * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
             *
             * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
             */
            function storeToken(token) {
              try {
                fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
              } catch (err) {
                if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
                  throw err;
                }
              }
              fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
              console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
            }

            /**
             * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
             *
             * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
             */
            function listFiles(auth) {
              var service = google.drive('v3');
              service.files.list({
                auth: auth,
                pageSize: 10,
                fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
              }, function(err, response) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                  return;
                }
                var files = response.files;
                if (files.length == 0) {
                  console.log('No files found.');
                } else {
                  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];
                    if(file.name.indexOf('Expense') > -1) {
                        downloadFile(file.id);
                    }


                  }
                }
              });
            }

            /**
             * Download a file's content.
             *
             * @param {File} file Drive File instance.
             * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
             */


            function downloadFile(fileId) {
            //file['exportLinks']['application/pdf'];

              //var fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
                    var service = google.drive('v3');
                    var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/test.doc');
                    service.files.get({
                       fileId: fileId,
                       alt: 'media'
                    })
                    .on('end', function() {
                      console.log('Done');
                    })
                    .on('error', function(err) {
                      console.log('Error during download', err);
                    })
                    .pipe(dest);

            }
```

I have only tried 17-20 requests in the last hour and don't think I have used all my quotas. I have checked that the GDrive api is enabled in my project. Please help.

Comment: Adding the output for better understanding.
Done
    { [Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.]
      code: 403,
      errors:
       [ { domain: 'usageLimits',
        reason: 'dailyLimitExceededUnreg',
        message: 'Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.',
        extendedHelp: 'https://code.google.com/apis/console' } 
    ] }

Comment: that error means that your request was missing an Authorization header

Comment: though there is a mention of an authorization header in the documentation , in the example there is no mention of this header. Would you please provide any working sample as I am clueless on this.

Comment: same problem never answered

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_user_rate_limit_exceeded), error 403 means that you have reached Google Drive API's maximum request rate. The limit varies depending on the kind of requests. The suggested action is to [Batch the requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch). Try to reduce the number of HTTP connections your client has to make.

Another workaround is to check the status for Google+ API in developer console. It should be set to `ON`. Wait for a few minutes after turning on, and ensure that you get a fresh token.

Check these related SO questions:

- [Keep getting a "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup" when attempting to google plus login on my web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335503/keep-getting-a-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-continued-use-requ)
- [Error code 403 in Google+ api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512203/error-code-403-in-google-api)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as I have mentioned its only 17-20 request for a day, So I dont think I have reached the maximum request rate. Secondly I have checked that the GDrive api is enabled for my app in the api console. So I am afraid it does not solve the issue.

Comment: i have a similar issue. did you resolve it subhankar?