# Google Drive API message "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded." while viewing files from Salesforce

Tags: google-drive-api, salesforce, apex

I created a service account, got json configuration file and I request an access token using it. The response is ok, I receive token. When I upload file using it everything is ok, but when I try to view files from a folder it returns error message

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires
>   signup.

My service account only needs to access own files, it doesn't access files of any other users.
My code for viewing files (right now I try to debug the response):

```
public List<String> getFilesList() {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?accessToken='+accessToken');
    HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
    System.debug(resp);
    System.debug(resp.getBody());
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. I was sending access token in the url address instead of in the header. Eventually I did it like this:

```
public List<String> getFilesList() {
 Http http = new Http();
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setMethod('GET');
 req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files);
 req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken);
 HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
 return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the error [**Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires sign**](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-create-public-api-key/), try to check in your Google developer console under APIs,  the project associated with the API key. Example: `https://console.developers.google.com/project/<your app id>/apiui/api`. Make sure that the status for Google+API was set to ON.

Based from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512203/error-code-403-in-google-api), that error implies that you haven't set up a Google APIs console project.

> 1. Create a [Google APIs Console project](https://code.google.com/apis/console)
> 2. On the [Services pane](https://code.google.com/apis/console#:services), enable all of
>      the APIs that your project requires.
> 3. On the [API Access pane](https://code.google.com/apis/console#:access), click **Create an
>      OAuth 2.0 client ID**. A dialog opens. Fill in your project's
>      information. Click **Next**
> 4. Choose the appropriate application type. Based on the tags you used for this post, I am guessing this is an iOS project so select
>      **Installed application**.
> 5. Enter your bundle ID. You don't need to enter an App Store ID until your app is listed there.
> 6. Click **Create Client ID**.
>
> You will see the client ID and client secret values. You will use
>   these values to enable communication with your project and the Google
>   APIs.
>
> If you aren't already using it, see the [Google+ iOS SDK and
>   documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/) for a full
>   walk through. The task called "write moments" is similar in
>   implementation and demonstrates how to connect to and use the Google+
>   REST APIs from within an iOS project that uses the SDK.
>
> You'll need to specify the scope of plus.me to get the profile
>   information.

Hope this helps!