# ChatFuel - Google Drive - Get file content using GET method via URL

Tags: google-drive-api, chatbot, chatfuel

I am developing a Fuel chatbot that gets file's content from Google drive to build gallery.
I am using JSON API (Fuel chatbot) to get the JSON response.
My file in drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx79Tkj95Q3iNmVHOFN0Q3BITE0/view
I want to get JSON response like:

```html
{
 "messages": [
    {
      "attachment":{
        "type":"template",
        "payload":{
          "template_type":"generic",
          "elements":[
            {
              "title":"Classic White T-Shirt",
              "image_url":"http://petersapparel.parseapp.com/img/item100-thumb.png",
              "subtitle":"Soft white cotton t-shirt is back in style",
              "buttons":[
                {
                  "type":"web_url",
                  "url":"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com/view_item?item_id=100",
                  "title":"View Item"
                },
                {
                  "type":"web_url",
                  "url":"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com/buy_item?item_id=100",
                  "title":"Buy Item"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "title":"Classic Grey T-Shirt",
              "image_url":"http://petersapparel.parseapp.com/img/item101-thumb.png",
              "subtitle":"Soft gray cotton t-shirt is back in style",
              "buttons":[
                {
                  "type":"web_url",
                  "url":"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com/view_item?item_id=101",
                  "title":"View Item"
                },
                {
                  "type":"web_url",
                  "url":"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com/buy_item?item_id=101",
                  "title":"Buy Item"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to get the content of the file by URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0Bx79Tkj95Q3iNmVHOFN0Q3BITE0/export?mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.file
```

But I got the response
[image: Drive response]

Do you have any suggestion to get the JSON response ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors) and test again.

Your error is:

> 403: Daily Limit Exceeded
>
> The Courtesy API limit for your project has been reached.
>
> ```
> {
>   "error": {
>     "errors": [
>       {
>         "domain": "usageLimits",
>         "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
>         "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
>       }
>     ],
>     "code": 403,
>     "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Suggested action: Request additional quota**.

Based from the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790658/google-drive-api-message-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-while-v), you may do the following to get rid of your error.

> 1. Create a [Google APIs Console project](https://code.google.com/apis/console)
> 2. On the [Services pane](https://code.google.com/apis/console#:services), enable all of the APIs that your project requires.
> 3. On the [API Access pane](https://code.google.com/apis/console#:access), click **Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID**. A dialog opens. Fill in your project's information. Click
>      **Next**
> 4. Choose the appropriate application type. Based on the tags you used for this post, I am guessing this is an iOS project so select
>      **Installed application**.
> 5. Enter your bundle ID. You don't need to enter an App Store ID until your app is listed there.
> 6. Click **Create Client ID**.
>
> You will see the client ID and client secret values. You will use
>   these values to enable communication with your project and the Google
>   APIs.
>
> If you aren't already using it, see the [Google+ iOS SDK and
>   documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/) for a full walk through. The task called "write
>   moments" is similar in implementation and demonstrates how to connect
>   to and use the Google+ REST APIs from within an iOS project that uses
>   the SDK.
>
> You'll need to specify the scope of plus.me to get the profile
>   information.

Hope this helps.