# How can I solve Error 403: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup. in google drive api with python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm coding an application in python that connects to google drive api using a service account. It works fine connecting and creating a file, but when I'm try to download a file, throws next error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

My code is like this

```
def credentials_from_file():

from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

    SCOPES = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    ]

    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = './client_secrets.json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    return credentials

credentials = credentials_from_file()
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Create a folder

folder_metadata = {
    'name': 'My_Files',    
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
}
cloudFolder = service.files().create(body=folder_metadata).execute()

print ('creado folder: %s' % cloudFolder.get('name'))
print ('id: %s' % cloudFolder.get('id'))
folder_id = cloudFolder.get('id')

# Upload a file in the folder
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'A Test File.txt',
    'parents': [cloudFolder['id']]
}

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as tf:
    tf.write("This is some test data.")
    media = MediaFileUpload(tf.name, mimetype='text/plain')
    cloudFile = service.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()

# List files in our folder
query = "'{}' in parents".format(cloudFolder['id'])
filesInFolder = service.files().list(q=query, orderBy='folder', 
pageSize=10).execute()
items = filesInFolder.get('files', [])

# Print the paged results
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

#downloading file ---- here is where my code crashes
request = service.files().get_media(fileId=cloudFile['id'])
print("Request: \n")
print(request)

fh = io.BytesIO()
print ("Download File..."+cloudFile['id'])

downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = Fenter code herealse
while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ('Download '+coludFile['name']+' %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

credentials file structure is like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "some-project",
  "private_key_id": "abc1234abc",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\BLAH BLAH BLAH\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "my_email@my_domain.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1234567890987654321",
  "auth_uri": "auth uri",
  "token_uri": "token uri",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "cert url",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "client cert url"
}
```

Could you help me to find what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You've just done one to many requests, sign up or do less requests

Comment: Isn’t the error message rather self explanatory?

Comment: Check out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38801440/11551468)

Comment: all of the comments above are wrong. The error message means that you have submitted a Drive request without an Access Token the http Authorization header. If you search SO you will see many correct answers.